# Every Apache request returns a AH01797 error

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04

Every request to the Apache server is returning an access error in the **error.log** file. This happens both on 404 and when the file is returned successfully. Here is the example error that is logged for a given file:

[Tue May 19 14:10:12.268558 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 28303] [client x.x.x.x:62392] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/...

Do you know what could be causing this? My error.log file is huge and hard to use for its intended purpose.

I am running Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

Comment: A directive in your server configuration causes this.

Comment: And it is worthwhile to note that the content of a `.htaccess` file is also a server configuration file (in addition to the conventional httpd.conf and other configuration files)